# Modern page how to set default calculated date

Tags: sharepoint-online, template, modern-pages

Working with a online teamsite and trying to set up some templates for folks to use when creating various kinds of pages. We are creating some "Knowledge Base" type pages to collect various procedures we use within our team. I want the template so that folks can easily create KB pages versus regular site pages or whatever other type of pages we might eventually have on this site.

I was able to add a *Review date* column to the site pages library which I want to default to one year from create date. I assigned it a default value of **=Today+365**. This works if I just create a new page without using a template.

If I create a new site page using my template, the review date column is either blank (a template created before I add the default value) or a static date from when I created the template. When I edit the template page details I can change the default value to any static value, but I can't put a formula/calculation in there.

Is there any way to have a calculated default value for a date column when using a template?

Comment: Rothrock, ever find a solution to this? I'm facing this exact issue.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? If not, were you able to work around the issue?

Answer (score 0):

So I have run a bunch of tests and reproduced this issue, here’s what I found:

The Site Pages you create using the custom template doesn’t have the *Review Date* column filled because the template itself is leaving this field empty. The pages created from template will carry every column value from the template.

You can check the templates under the "Template" folder in the Site Page library to see if you are in the same situation.

If you are, here’s my suggestion:

Since you have the column set in the Site Page library, recreate the site page with or without a template. Save it as a template so that it will have the calculated value in the *Review Date* field.

You can manually give your existing templates a *Review Date* value, but it won’t be a calculated value.

Ps. I’m using `=Today()+365` as the formula.